# Mathematical expression of latitude of point on great circle in objective c

Tags: objective-c, math, mapkit, cllocation, great-circle

I am trying to calculate Latitude of known Longtitude of exact point on great circle (straight path between two points on the surface of sphere) and need to exprees next formula:

```
ϕ = arctg [ tgϕ2sin(λ-λ1) ] / sin(λ2-λ1) + [ tgϕ1sin(λ2-λ) ] / sin(λ2-λ1)
```

in objective c (or c++) code. I am doing this one:

```
f = atan(((tan(f2) * sin(l - l1)) / sin(l2 - l1)) + ((tan(f1) * sin (l2 - l))/sin(l2-l1)));
```

But it's doesnt work. I checked the calculation of my objective-c expression with calculation on my scientific calculator and they are not equal. Diference is great!!! And therefore Latitude of point are also incorrect. I saw it on the MapView in my application.

Whats wrong?

Comment: I'll guess you're using degrees when you should be using radians or visa versa.  Objective-C, and all the curly brace languages, assume radians for angles in trig functions.

Comment: To expand on duffymo's comment. This will probably help you: `#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle/180.0)*M_PI)`

Comment: forgot: `#define M_PI   3.14159265358979323846264338327950288`

Comment: @Filip: `M_PI` is already defined in math.h.

Comment: @MartinR Ohh, nifty! ;)

Comment: Oh yeaaahhh! A lot of thanks gays! Its done.